# Pycharm console eats django-nose coverage output

Tags: django, code-coverage, pycharm, nose

I'm trying to perform testing with coverage on a django application within pycharm itself. I'm using django-nose / nose as the test runner and I have these settings in test_settings.py

```
# nose settings
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=myapp',
]
```

This all works very nicely if I go to the command line (or the builtin pycharm terminal) activate my virtualenv and run... `django-admin.py test --settings=myapp.tests.test_settings`... I get the output I expect.

However when I try to use my test run config inside Pycharm, I no longer get the coverage output, all I get is:

```
Testing started at 16:37 ...
There is no such manage file manage
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=dynamicbanners --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..
Process finished with exit code 0
```

(I don't have a manage.py as it is a standalone app, hence the manage file message I assume).

The tests still "pass" but there is no output and no .coverage file created. I am running on windows temporarily, is it possible that windows is denying access to writing the .coverage file and thus nothing is being displayed? Or is Pycharm eating the output but failing to display it?

I would use the builtin pycharm "Run with coverage" option, but it seems to have a problem with

```
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=myapp',
]
```

because when I run it with those options it spits out an error which I believe is due to two instances of coverage being initialised

```
Testing started at 16:41 ...
There is no such manage file manage
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=myapp --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.0.1\helpers\run_coverage.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ptinkler\venvs\myapp_venv\lib\site-packages\coverage\cmdline.py", line 720, in main
    status = CoverageScript().command_line(argv)
  File "C:\Users\ptinkler\venvs\myapp_venv\lib\site-packages\coverage\cmdline.py", line 438, in command_line
     self.do_execute(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\ptinkler\venvs\myapp_venv\lib\site-packages\coverage\cmdline.py", line 580, in do_execute
     self.coverage.stop()
  File "C:\Users\ptinkler\venvs\myapp_venv\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py", line 410, in stop
     self.collector.stop()
  File "C:\Users\ptinkler\venvs\myapp_venv\lib\site-packages\coverage\collector.py", line 294, in stop
     assert self._collectors[-1] is self
AssertionError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is despite me having unchecked "use bundled coverage.py" in settings -> coverage

Would appreciate any assistance, I'd rather not have to create a local settings file to get rid of those `NOSE_ARGS` just to get coverage displaying within pycharm. If I can only end up with standard coverage output in the pycharm testrunner console that's not the end of the world. Otherwise I guess I'll have to stick to commandline.

Comment: Have you tried `--cover-html`? Coverage makes such a beautiful output in html that I almost never use command line output when running my tests.

Comment: I'll try that but is there any reason to suspect it won't just do exactly the same as the --cover-xml option and refuse to output the file when run from within Pycharm?

Comment: same problems after years, how is this solved?